# Expected Value of Fewest Dots On the Unit Square

Tags: pr.probability

Let $n$ random lines be put through the unit square, by starting with a randomly selected point on one side of the unit square, and then drawing the segment to a random point from any of the three alternate sides of the square.

What is the lowest expected value of times a line will intersect a side of the square. Or in other words, what on average will be the lowest number of intersections on any of the four sides with $n$ lines.

I can already see that the probability that a line is not hit is $(3/4)(2/3)=1/2$ after each line and so generally the probability could be given as:

$p(n) = \binom n 1 (1/2)^n + \binom n 2 (1/2)^n +.....$

However I cannot find the expected value. Am I on the right track? What is the expected value?

Comment: One expression, admittedly hard to use, is $$n!\sum_{a+b+c+d+e+f=n}\frac{\min(a+b+c, a+d+e, b+d+f, c+e+f)}{a!\ b!\ c!\ d! \ e! \ f!}$$ where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are the counts for the six pairs of sides which the lines might connect.